# What's stopping Jenkins ClearCase plugin from seeing baseline components?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

I've upgraded Jenkins ClearCase Plugin and my build job is no longer able to determine load rules properly. Things worked before the plugin upgrade.

**Environment**

```
CC Plugin: org.jenkins-ci.plugins:clearcase:1.5.3
Jenkins: 1.596
I'm using UCM ClearCase as Source Code Management. 
Jenkins builds a new snapshot view on each job execution.
```

**Issue**

I have three baselines in the stream. The console output shows that plugin sees all of these baselines. However, from two of these baselines, the plugin is unable to determine components.

Command `[workspace] $ cleartool lsbl -fmt %[depends_on_closure]Xp baseline:bn1@\xyz` is listed in the console output. It is followed by a blank line. When I execute this command in DOS prompt, I also get nothing.

Command `[workspace] $ cleartool lsbl -fmt %[depends_on_closure]Xp baseline:bn3@\xyz` is listed in the console output. It is followed by a line listing components.

So, out of three baselines, one is working and its components are read and added to load rules properly. The view is built but since load rules are missing components from two other baselines, the view can't be properly updated.

**Explicit load rule list works**

The plugin allows to list load rules explicitly (Define load rules manually). When I do that, view is built and updated properly.

What could be preventing the newest plugin from seeing components and building load rules dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

When you compare [what has been changed in the latest release](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/compare/clearcase-1.5.2...clearcase-1.5.3) of the [Jenkins ClearCase plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin), you see [commit f2c0eb8: "When view is invalid, we should build immediately, it is useless to determine the remote baseline"](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/commit/f2c0eb86e3a0efafc4adf20b8bb1a7b9228def09): that seems the only commit which might be somewhat related to not computing baselines.

If that isn't it (meaning the view is perfectly fine, and the `lsbl` should work), it is a bug which needs to be reported to the [Jenkins ClearCase plugin issue tracker](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%29%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%27clearcase-plugin%27) (and/or [the one for the ClearCase UCM plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%29%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%27clearcase-ucm-plugin%27)).

[`cleartool lsbl`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsbl.htm?lang=en) is here used with [`fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?lang=en) option "`depends_on_closure`": lists All of the baselines in the full dependence graph of a composite baseline.

> Jenkins shows "Downgrade to 1.3.11"

Most of the changes happened [between 1.3.19 and 1.4](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/compare/clearcase-1.3.19...clearcase-1.4), including [`clearcase/ucm/service/BaselineService.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/blob/685e4e50bd87872ec7f6d0ad88c0dffd43651a0f/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/ucm/service/BaselineService.java), which uses the `lsbl -fmt`.

Comment: The first command listed in my question queries the stream before the view is built. It has the right baseline. It just won't read the components from that baseline. The view itself is built fine and only fails proper update because load rules are not set correctly. This looks like a problem with querying a baseline on the stream and not an issue with the view.

Comment: @user2984213 i agree. I was just pointing to the only significant change between 1.5.2 and 1.5.3. What version did you have before upgrading that plugin?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not kept the previous version of the plugin. It was certainly a much earlier version than 1.5.2. Any idea what [depends_on_closure] does? Can it be hinting at a component configuration miss on the stream that the older plugin was able to ignore?

Comment: Jenkins shows "Downgrade to 1.3.11" under Previously Installed  Version column.

Comment: @user2984213 ok let me check. Did you touch to the ClearCase UCM plugin as well?

Comment: I only have this ClearCase plugin installed: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin  . No other ClearCase plugins. I haven't removed any, either. Just updated this only one that we had.

Comment: @user2984213 I have edited the answer a bit. Would those `cleartool lsbl` fail as well if you were to do them in a shell? (meaning outside of the context of a Jenkins job, so just manually in a shell)

Comment: That first quoted command executed in DOS prompt also yields nothing. I'm just wondering why the plugin feels it should send it to clearcase.